# Go from SKView back to UIView

Tags: uiview, sprite-kit

I have two parts to my project. Part one is made in the storyboard, and the second is an SKView. How can I go from my second part in the SKView back to the main UIView?

Comment: you mean how to segue from one storyboard to another? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-storyboard/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: Thanks for the help on both my questions, maybe you can answer this one: How can you put a SKView in a storyboard because that looks like what you're suggesting? Or am I misinterpreting you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create custom `ViewController`: File - New - File - Objective-C class. Enter a name: `GameSceneViewController`. Subclass of `UIViewController`.
2. Override `viewWillAppear` method:

   ```
   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

       GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
       scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

       [self.skView presentScene:scene];
   }
   ```

   `skView` property will be an `IBOutlet` for `SKView`. Also make sure you've imported SpriteKit framework:

   ```
   #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
   ```
3. Add new `ViewController` to the storyboard.
4. In the Identity inspector enter a custom class for the added ViewController: `GameSceneViewController`

   [image: GameSceneViewController]
5. Add a subview to a root view:

   [image: GameSceneViewController]
6. In the Identity inspector enter a custom class for the added View: `SKView`

   [image: Custom class name]
7. Create an `IBOutlet` for the added `SKView`.

Now you should be able to use segues for switching between ViewControllers

Comment: amazingly detailed question, but I'm getting an error when trying to create an IBOutlet for the added SKView. It is saying that 'SKView' is an unknown type. Do I have to import something or am I doing this improperly?

Comment: You need to #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h> inside the file where you want to create the IBOutlet. I've edited my answer