# SpriteKit: SKScene Freeze when modal view pesented

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm having the following issue with SpriteKit. I'm presenting a modal viewController from another viewController which view is a SKView, the problem is that the SKScene in the SKView freezes when i dismiss the modal viewController, and it unfreezes if I present and dismiss the modal view again. It's toggling...

The weird thing is that when the scene unfreezes I can see that animations continued in the background as the sprites are in different positions than they where before the freeze.

To make things weirder, it only happens when testing in the actual device, not in the simulator.

I saw this question: [iAds and SpriteKit: SKScene Freeze on fullscreen exit on device only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358802/iads-and-spritekit-skscene-freeze-on-fullscreen-exit-on-device-only) but it has no answer and the problem is when using iAds. I've read in other forums that it can be solved by removing `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES`, but I'm not using iAds at all.

Please help, i'm desperate.

Comment: Have you tried pausing the scene when you change views?

Comment: Yes, I stop the calls for update on viewWillDisappear and resume on ViewWillAppear.

Comment: Any update on this as I am experiencing the exact same problems

Answer (score 4):

I had almost the same problem, this link helped me
[Go from SKView back to UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208579/go-from-skview-back-to-uiview)

The point is to make your skView a subview of an UIView and then make an IBOutlet that link to your skView.

That work with and without iAd Banner (in my case I made the banner a subview+iboutlet as well)

**How to reproduce the effect:**

Preparation:

1. Create a new SpriteKit project
2. Open Main_Iphone.storyboard
3. Add (drag/drop) a Tab bar controller
4. Delete Viewcontroller Item1
5. Create a Viewcontroller Segue from the tab bar controller to the original
   (Apple) viewcontroller (the one with the skview)
6. In View Controller properties click Is initial View Controller
7. Run on actual device

Action:

1. Go to Item tab click to launch Plane's animation
2. Click on Item 2
3. Click back to Item tab => **Plane is Frozen**
4. Click several time => nothing happen
5. Click on Item 2 and back to Item => Several Planes moving (**toggling effect**)

**How to Solve the problem:**

6. Drag a view onto the original (Apple) skview You should now have a
   parent/child link in the object navigator pane (left)
7. Permute the Custom Class properties, so that child is now SkView and Parent is
   UIView
8. Show the assistant editor with storyboard and ViewController.h
9. control-drag the skview to the interface and create an IBOutlet named skView

   ViewController.h:

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *skView;

   @end
   ```
10. in ViewController.m comment line 19 and replace skView by self.skView

    ```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        // Configure the view.
        //SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        self.skView.showsFPS = YES;
        self.skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [self.skView presentScene:scene];
    }
    ```
11. Run and now no more freeze

Regards

Answer (score 4):

In case you're still stuck on this, I had the same issue and it was caused by adding UIButtons as subviews on my SKView.

The fix for me was to make a UIView the base view of my view controller and then add the SKView as a subview. Any subviews you want to add (e.g. buttons) should be added to the UIView, **NOT** the SKView.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your exact same problem and, although I haven't found a reason for it, I have created a work-around instead.

I found that using a UIView instead of a UIViewController worked as the modal view seemed to be causing the issues. This didn't freeze the skscene (which seemed frozen as calling self.scene.view.paused = YES didn't do anything and checking if it is paused returns NO).

I added a uiview off the screen and then animated it on top of the scene then off again when I was done with it. I then used the function reloadScene to refresh the changes I had made to the scene:

```
- (void)reloadScene {

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [FlappyBirdCloneMainMenu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

This then solved the problem.

If you do find out why the freezing occurred definitely post the answer as I would be interested to know for future sprite kit reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it by moving the SKView to a subview of a UIView.

The original code in my view controller to create the SKView was as follows:

```
self.mySpriteKitView = (SKView *) self.view;
```

All I had to do to fix the issue was change it to this:

```
self.mySpriteKitView = [[SKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:self.mySpriteKitView];
```

Unfortunately, XCode's project template for a new SpriteKit project creates an SKView by casting the  view controller's self.view as shown above in my "original" code.  So unless you change the SKView creation code, you are going to end up with this bug if you call a modal view, such as an interstitial ad.