# SKView to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I am currently making an app that starts off using UIKit, and then transitions to SpriteKit. I now want to go from the SpriteKit part of my app back to UIKit. This made me wonder if there was a way to go from a SKView to a UIView using Swift. I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208579/go-from-skview-back-to-uiview) which shows how to do it, but using Objective-C.

Comment: What do you mean by "way to go from a SKView to a UIView"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKView` is a subclass of `UIView`. Everywhere you can use a `UIView`, you can also use an `SKView`. You can

> go from an `SKView` to an `UIView`

simply by casting it. For example:

```
let view = spriteKitView as UIView
```